# Элементы не центрируются внутри блока

Tags: html, css, display

```css
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo_mess{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
}

.logo_mess ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.logo_mess ul li{
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<body>

       <div class="logo_mess">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем при полном развернутом экране такой проблемы не наблюдается.

Comment: Манипуляции с margin: 0 auto; непосредственно на тег ul ничего не дают, так же как и приведение ul в блочный элемент. Шо за магия?!?!?!?

Comment: У `ul` `padding-left` есть, он обнулён?

Comment: "№"?%?*"%:"%, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простое, установите magin и padding 0.Некоторые браузеры используют отступы (Mozilla, Netscape, Safari), а другие используют поля (Internet Explorer, Opera) для установки величины отступа.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo_mess {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo_mess ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo_mess ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="logo_mess">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">asd</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Лет пять назад я по этой причине и бросил верстку... Уж лучше в c++ насиловать свой мозг.